# Displaying TextView in Fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display text in `Fragment41` automatically right after all rb are checked. How to make this text displayed in `Fragment41`? I tried several ways but I get confused about this implementation. And I know that method `getIntent().` here is wrong but I don't know what to change it for). Please help with all this.

My `Fragment41`

```
    package make.appaplication;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment41 extends Fragment {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_41, container, false);

        TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

        textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
    }
}
```

Here is `Fragment41` in `FragmentList` in `MainActivity`

```
fragmentList.add(new Fragment41());
```

And here is the code for `checkButton`

```
buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkAnswers())
                intent.putExtra("Key Answer", true);

            else
                intent.putExtra("Key Answer", false);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

**Just one more issue**

I have two `strings` "Good answers" and "Wrong answers" and the code for them is

```
buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkAnswers())
                intent.putExtra("Key Answer", true);

            else
                intent.putExtra("Key Answer", false);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

How to add to the above and below code, one more statement `string` "You haven't checked all answers"?

```
 textViewDisplayResult.setText(getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Key Answer", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getActivity().getIntent().get...` instead of just calling `getIntent()`. So the whole code in your fragment is:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_41, container, false);

    TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);
    textViewDisplayResult.setText(getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Key Answer", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);

    return view;
}
```

I think I already answered in your previous post.

And, of course I think you did it (if you didn't please read first the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding), you need to add your fragment to Activity:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment_41_instance).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

**Another issues**

```
buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!allAnswersChecked())
            intent.putExtra("Key Answer", 1);
        else if (checkAnswers()) 
            intent.putExtra("Key Answer", 2);
        else
            intent.putExtra("Key Answer", 3);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

And then:

```
int result = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("Key Answer", 1);
textViewDisplayResult.setText(result == 1 ? R.string.text_not_checked : 
    result == 2 ? R.string.Good_answer : R.string.Wrong_answer);
```

Comment: Great stuff. Many thanks Sergey :) Please have a look at my updated post - I can't solve one more issue. Maybe you can help.

Comment: Fantastic :) But Sergey, at the moment I have three questions and when I check only 2 `radioButtons` I get text `"You havent checked all answers"` which is fine, of course. But when come back to check the third rb, the text won't change automatically for "Good answers" or "Bad answers". Can we solve it somehow?

Comment: Do you have two activities? In first you have radio buttons in the second - fragment with the result text?

Comment: I have `Fragment1` with 3`radioButtons`, then `Fragment2` with 3 `radioButttons`, then `Fragment3` with 3 `radioButtons` and `Fragment41` to display `textView` which is "Good answers", "Wrong answers", "You havent checked all answers"

Comment: create another activity for the result text and add to it Fragment41

Comment: You mean separated `activity.java` and add to `Fragment41`? Please forgive me, I'm not that good in coding yet :)

Comment: Yes, separated activity(SecondActivity.java). Fragment41 should be added to the SecondActivity.java.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I get mistakes. Can we just leave as it is now `final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fragment41.class);` and display text in `Fragment41` using MainActivity?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't start your fragment with the intent. With intent you can start activities and services.

Comment: I follow you so. Just please let me know how to add a single `fragment` to `second activity`.

Comment: as you did it in first activity: getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment_41_instance).addToBackStack(null).commit();

Comment: Done, Sergey. What next?

Comment: I've just opened account on Linked. Sent you message (I think) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use same KEY `"Key Answer"` for both `put` and `get` extra data from `Intent`.

**Update `Fragment41` as below**

```
package make.appaplication;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment41 extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_41, container, false);

        TextView textViewDisplayResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_display_result);

        boolean isAnswered = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("is_answered");
        if (isAnswered)
            textViewDisplayResult.setText(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Key Answer", false)?R.string.Good_answer:R.string.Wrong_answer);
        else
            textViewDisplayResult.setText("You haven't checked all answers");

        return view;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Use a `boolean` variable `isAnswered` to check weather user answered or not. Pass this value to fragment using KEY `is_answered`.

```
buttonCheckAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (isAnswered)
                intent.putExtra("is_answered", true);
            else
            {
                if (checkAnswers())
                   intent.putExtra("Key Answer", true);
                else
                   intent.putExtra("Key Answer", false);

                intent.putExtra("is_answered", false);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Ferdous. I just don't understand what you mean by `Use same KEY "Key Answer" for both put and get extra data from Intent`

Comment: In your Fragment you have used>> getBooleanExtra("KEY_ANSWER", false) but in your onclick listener you used >>intent.putExtra("Key Answer", true);  You should use "Key Answer" both in fragment and onclick listener

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right, Ferdous. That is what I'm trying to do at the moment. Please have a look at my updated post with **Just one more issue**. Maybe you can help.

Comment: what you want actually when button click?

Comment: @Melisa Try my updated answer. Update your fragment and button onclick listener as i mentioned above. Hope this will work

Comment: Thank you Ferdous. That helps a lot!

Comment: If my answer seems useful and solves your problem then its better to accept this answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: I got a bit confused about this code and also don't know how to implement it correctly in my `Fragment41` :) Maybe we can work it out:)

Comment: Ferdous, could you please suggest me how to get this final text change **automatically** according to whatever is the outcome - either good answers, wrong answers or not checked all rb?